# How to access a specific part of req.body (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been trying to specific access a nested property of req.body the output however is always undefined 
the code is as follows

```
  let dataRecieved = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        console.log(dataRecieved);
        let refCode = dataRecieved["refferal"];
```

and the output in the terminal is

```
{"name":"","phone":"","emailid":"","refferal":"gg","time":"Sat Oct 05 2019 08:14:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}
undefined
```

the second undefined is when i ask for the refferal object of req.body

Comment: why do you `JSON.stringify` it ? You are turning object into JSON, therefore you don't have access to individual properties.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake you made is converting the JSON object into a string. One way you can access data inside a JSON object using . operator. Therefore try below code snippet to access data inside the object.

```
let dataRecieved = req.body;
console.log(dataRecieved.name);
```

Considering the best practices either you can lodash[(https://lodash.com/](https://lodash.com/)) or object destructuring[(ES6 destructuring)](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/) based on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `body-parser` middleware is installed

```
const app = require('express')()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

after that you can access `req.body` directly as a object

```
app.post('*' (res, req) => {
  let dataRecieved  = req.body
})
```